# Login facebook sdk for unity problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have a prolem when i used facebook sdk for unity when login on android (real device - Gooogle nexus 7 2012).
- adb logcat this error:
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494): Exception during service
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash rhDpGcyTNP33kRZOYIKdOcoevoM does not match any stored key hashes.
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:83)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:162)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponse.h(ApiResponse.java:239)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:272)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:29)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:59)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:29)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:363)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:179)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.b(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:139)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:237)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:378)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:156)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:16)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:366)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:259)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:299)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:53)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:230)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:59)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
W/Bundle  (12430): Key com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_VERSION expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value  was returned.
W/Bundle  (12430): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
W/Bundle  (12430): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

.....
....
V/FBUnitySDK(21692): sending to Unity OnLoginComplete({"cancelled":true})
I/Unity   (21692): call login:
I/Unity   (21692):
I/Unity   (21692): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)
I/Unity   (21692):
I/Unity   (21692): login result: {"is_logged_in":false,"user_id":"","access_token":""}
I/Unity   (21692):
I/Unity   (21692): (Filename: ./Runtime/ExportGenerated/AndroidManaged/UnityEngineDebug.cpp Line: 54)

- When i uninstall facebook app, this app working fine.
- I think this error occur because my key hash.
  Please help me out this problem. (Sorry my english not good)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key hash you're passing to the Facebook SDK isn't stored with your developer account.

```
W/fb4a(:):BlueServiceQueue(10494): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash rhDpGcyTNP33kRZOYIKdOcoevoM does not match any stored key hashes.
```

Go to developers.facebook.com/apps/ and add it in the android section  (key hash rhDpGcyTNP33kRZOYIKdOcoevoM)